# How do I make dates legit/safe before passing it to strtotime()?

Tags: php, sanitization, strtotime

Here is what I have now.

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']))));
```

I was told that I need to make sure that the `$date` is safe/legit before passing it to `strtotime()`. How do I do that? I've looked up https://www.php.net/strtotime but it really doesn't tell me what I'm looking for I think.

Can someone explain to me in a little better detail how to clean submit to strtotime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is by far overkill from what you need to do. The strtotime() function should do all the "validation" you need - either it will return a valid date, or not. After that, you should not need to trim or escape the output from date() - the output is determined by you. Here is what I would do:

```
$date = strtotime($_POST['date']);
if($date) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $date);
    //do stuff based on valid date
}
else {
    //handle invalid date. 
}
```

Comment: The reason I am asking is because I have this code: `echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="' . $row['date'] . '" /></div>';` ,and I'm looking to make it "safe" because someone told me it wasn't.  How would the code you showed work in this situation?

Comment: where is $row['date'] coming from? As to why my method is safe - `strtotime()` can safely convert a string to an integer on its own. Once you pass inputs though it, you shouldn't have to worry about them (as long as you don't directly access the inputs afterward). The if in my post is to handle cases where `strtotime()` fails and returns false.

Comment: Is it possible that they were referring to making sure the date was in the correct format. Consider '12/12/12', this would be ambiguous when being passed to strtotime. A solution would either to use the date_create_from_format or to split the date using explode (or similar) and reconstruct to a non-ambiguous form

Comment: PaulBain is right - there is definitely a chance the date won't be interpreted correctly. In terms of "safe" though, i assume from hackers - you should be fine.

Comment: @MrGlass so realistically the way I have it, although overkill will work? I don't mind changing my code to fit the situation, but I was more curious about how things work that's all :)

Comment: Yes. in fact, just `$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']));` would work fine.

Answer (score 6):

There's no real reason to sanitize the value beforehand. The worst thing that can happen is that the time isn't valid and `strtotime()` returns false (which you can also use to check whether the date string was valid).

Also, there's no reason to trim and escape the `date( 'Y-m-d' )` function's return value: it will never return values with trailing whitespace or anything that should be escaped.

Comment: +1 but also check [strtotime's notes](http://uk3.php.net/strtotime#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes): depending on the format of your date field your results may be unexpected (specifically US/EU dates).

Comment: @Juhana it won't be affected by injections?

Comment: @MattRidge What kind of injections? `strtotime( $x )` returns either `false` or an integer, depending on the value of `$x`. There's no way anyone can attack your database with a number.